# In extjs4 how to create tpl for grid column as required

Tags: grid, extjs4

i am working in extjs4. I have model with following fields:

```
{name : 'accept' , type : 'Int'},
{name : 'reject' , type : 'Int'},
{name : 'pending' , type : 'Int'},
{name : 'review' , type : 'Int'}
```

I have grid with it one of column namely status. In this column i want to show imageicon depending upon above model fields.For accept = '*' , reject = '+' , pending = '--' , 
review = '!!' i want to show these images under this single column. e.g. if accept field is having value as 3 and reject value is 2 then i want to show only these two imageicons, not pending and review icons. If all are having values, i want to show all icons. So how to apply such column to grid? How to create template for such column in extjs4?

Answer (score 1):

You should specify your own **renderer** for the column.
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-renderer

You can implement behaviour which you want to have.
To render images use html image tags with links to your resources in **return** statement.

Comment: thanx for reply sir. but to renderer function we can pass only one value. i want to perform check using four values. So can you please elaborate how i need to do in such case

Comment: Look provided link again - renderer has 7 arguments. The third is a record, your model. So all fields are accessible. Example is not full.

Comment: thanx sir...by using model as parameter, its working